# Calculate two numbers inside each function with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new in JS and jQuery and I came across a problem that can't figure it out.

I have 3 buttons, each of those buttons has 2 numbers, one is quantity and the other is the price.

How can I get the correct new price with multiplication for each button on click?

My code:

```js
let topSalePrice = $("#topSalePrice");
let topRegPrice = $("#topRegPrice");
let quantity = $(".quantity");
let price = $(".price");
let button = $(".button")

topSalePrice = topSalePrice.text().substr(0, topSalePrice.text().indexOf('€'));
topSalePrice = topSalePrice.replace(/,/g, '.');

price.each(function() {
  price = $(this);
  price = $(this).text().substr(0, $(this).text().indexOf('€'));
  price = price.replace(/,/g, '.');
  console.log("Price = " + price)
  return
});

quantity.each(function() {
  quantity = $(this).text();
  console.log("Quantity = " + quantity)
});

button.each(function() {
  $(this).click(function() {
    newPrice = price * quantity;
    console.log("New Price = " + newPrice);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Sale Price
<div id="topSalePrice">9,99€</div>
Regular Price
<div id="topRegPrice">7,99€</div>

<div class="button">
  <div class="quantity">1</div>
  <div class="price">7,99€</div>
</div>
<div class="button">
  <div class="quantity">2</div>
  <div class="price">6,99€</div>
</div>
<div class="button">
  <div class="quantity">3</div>
  <div class="price">5,99€</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML comes with an argument called `data-{SOME-NAME}` which can hold arbitrary data for a tag.

In your case, I've used the `data-price` to store the price value, and the `data-quantity` to store the quantity value.

Then the `jQuery` comes with a method called `data` that accepts as an argument the right part of the data attribute.

So for example, for the `data-price` I've used the `data` method as `data('price')` and for the `data-quantity` I've used the `data('quantity')`.

Worth mentioned, that JavaScript comes also with its own implementation to get the data from a `data-` attribute.

So, for example, if you used the native javascript implementation for the same results the code should be like that:

```
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.button');

if ( buttons ) {
    buttons.forEach(
        function(button) {
            let price = button.querySelector('.price');
            let quantity = button.querySelector('.quantity');
    
            console.log('Price :', price.dataset.price)
            console.log('Quantity :', quantity.dataset.quantity)
        }
    );
}
```

*(The above code snippet, is written from my mind. I didn't test it on my console, so it's possible to contain errors. But generally speaking, this is how it looks like the native solution :) )*

```js
let topSalePrice = $("#topSalePrice");
let topRegPrice = $("#topRegPrice");
let quantity = $(".quantity");
let price = $(".price");
let button = $(".button")

let topPrice = topSalePrice.data('price');
let regularPrice = topRegPrice.data('price');
console.log('Top Sale Price: ' + topPrice);
console.log('Top Regular Price: ' + regularPrice);

button.each(function() {
  $(this).click(
    function() {
      // Here, what I do, is to Query the DOM to find inside the Button, the two elements. The .price and the .quantity.
      let price = $(this).find('.price').first().data('price');
      let quantity = $(this).find('.quantity').first().data('quantity');

      newPrice = price * quantity;
      console.log("New Price = " + newPrice);
    }
  )
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Sale Price
<div 
  id="topSalePrice"
  data-price='9.99'
>
  9,99€
</div>

Regular Price
<div 
  id="topRegPrice"
  data-price='7.99'
>
  7,99€
</div>

<div class="button">
  <div 
    class="quantity"
    data-quantity="1"
  >
    1
  </div>
  <div 
    class="price"
    data-price='7.99'
  >
    7,99€
  </div>
</div>
<div class="button">
  <div 
    class="quantity"
    data-quantity="2"
  >
    2
  </div>
  <div 
    class="price"
    data-price='6.99'
  >
    6,99€
  </div>
</div>
<div class="button">
  <div 
    class="quantity"
    data-quantity="3"
  >3</div>
  <div 
    class="price"
    data-price='5.99'
  >
    5,99€
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I see u added data-price and data quantity attributes to divs. What if I want to use text inside div as value? I need to trim price to numbers and replace comma with dot right?

Comment: @MiranUrbas it's safer to go the way I describe above, as you have the option to have the data in the right format from ahead of time. If anyway you want to have the text, then yes, you have to sanitize the values. You should remove spaces, special characters, make sure the value is decimal _(for the price)_, and then make your calculations, but this way is more error-prone.

Comment: @MiranUrbas finally, if you are happy with my answer don't forget to upvote too :) Thank you.

Comment: Yes your answer is perfect, great explanation. I did upvote, but it says that is recorded but not publicly viewed because I'm new 

Comment: xaxaxaxa No worries @MiranUrbas. Thank you very much anyway :) ;) Good luck with what you do.

Answer (score 0):

well u can do this way , here is demo code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Demo code</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="button" onclick="result(1,799)">
  <div class="quantity">1</div>
  <div class="price">7,99€</div>
</div>
<script>
function result(q,p){
console.log('New Price is' + ' '+ (parseInt(q)*parseInt(p))); 
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**i did in vanilla js , u can convert into jquery easily**

Comment: well yeah, but if value is dynamic then just passing those value in result function which are in div will work !!